# How to resolve cyclic dependency in defining generic models in django

Tags: python, django, generics, django-models

I want to define a generic model, which can be used in any app. Following are the definitions of my generic models:-

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
#  This mixin is used to track the user, who has created this object.
class OwnedModel(models.Model):
       owner           = ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, editable=False)

      class Meta:
            abstract    = True

#   AreaOrVillage extending this model, will also get owner field, which
#   refer to User.
class AreaOrVillage(OwnedModel):

    area_village_name   = LocationIdentifierField(name="areaOrVillageName", verbose_name="Area/Village:", blank=False, null=False)
    area_village_code   = LocationCodeField(name="areaOrVillageCode", verbose_name="Area/Village Code", null=True, blank=True)
    zipcode             = ZipCodeField(verbose_name="ZipCode", null=False, blank=False)
    #  It's another model, referred by this model
    tehsil              = models.ForeignKey(to=Tehsil, related_name="areas_or_villages")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Areas/Villages"
        unique_together     = ("tehsil", "areaOrVillageName")
        ordering            = ("tehsil", "areaOrVillageName")
        app_label           = 'location_app'

    def __str__(self):
        text                = self.to_str()
        return "{}{}{}".format(text, ", " if text and self.tehsil else "",
                               self.tehsil.__str__() if self.tehsil else "")

    def to_str(self):
        return "%s" %(self.areaOrVillageName or self.areaOrVillageCode)
```

Now, In my django project, I have overridden default user model as follow(which makes use of generic models, defined above) :-

```
class PSS_User_Type(ModelBase):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dictattrs):
        user_type = super(PSS_User_Type, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dictattrs)

        OVER_RIDDEN_ATTR    = "is_staff"
        NEW_ATTR            = "is_devteam_member"

        if hasattr(user_type, OVER_RIDDEN_ATTR):
            setattr(user_type, NEW_ATTR,
                    getattr(user_type, OVER_RIDDEN_ATTR))
            delattr(user_type, OVER_RIDDEN_ATTR)

            setattr(user_type, "__getattr__", PSS_User_Type.__getattr__)

        def __getattr__(self, attrname):
            effective_attr = NEW_ATTR if attrname == OVER_RIDDEN_ATTR else attrname
            return super(cls, self).__getattr__(attrname)

        return user_type

class PSS_User(LoggableModel, OwnedModel, ResolvableModelMixin, AbstractUser):

    __metaclass__ = PSS_User_Type

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                        'village', 'gotra']

    #   TODO :- Add phone/mobile no details

    dob = DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    age = SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, validators=[AgeValidator()])
    is_alive = BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=True)
    gender  = GenderField(null=False, blank=False)
    user_village = ForeignKey(to=AreaOrVillage, null=False, related_name="gram_vasi")
```

Now, it's introducing cyclic dependency problem, since generic models are depending on user, to track their creator, user definition also makes use of generic model, due to which running migration against db is giving problem

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_pss_user" does not exist
```

Is there any better way to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `to` field in the `ForeignKey` [can also be a string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, **you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself**:

(emphasis added)

For example, from your code, you could do the following:

```
user_village = ForeignKey(to='AreaOrVillage', null=False, related_name="gram_vasi")
```

Use that syntax on all of your `ForeignKey` fields, and you’ll avoid any circular references.

Comment: It's giving me error:  users.PSS_User.user_village: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'AreaOrVillage', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

Comment: Did you use this syntax for **all** of you `ForeignKey` fields?

Comment: Yes, I have used this syntax for foreignkey. Btw, app name have also to be included, so, I have set 'appname.modelname' in to argument of ForeignKey()